# Выводится только первая строка

Tags: php, mysql

Содержание таблицы `sites`:

```
id=1 url=a.php
id=2 url=b.php
```

Скрипт:

```
<?php
include('config.php');//тут данные host/user/pass/db
$query = mysql_query("SELECT url from sites",$db);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Выводит только `a.php`, в чем дело?

Comment: @Семён Савенко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ну так вы получаете все строки, а выводите только одну. Строка `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);` в цикле должна быть:

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    var_dump($result);
}
```

UPD: см. примеры в [доках](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). И да, надо на mysqli переходить, т.к. mysql устаревшее расширение.

Comment: @BOPOH, тогда уж на PDO :)